# getting html and jscript to validate a password?

Tags: javascript, html

just a quick question as im unsure why this is not working

html:

```
<label>Password </label> <input type="password" id="pword"><br>
<label>Confirm Password </label>  <input type="password" id="confpword"><br>
```

js:

```
function passwordValidation(){

    var username = document.getElementById("unamem");
    var password1 = document.getElementById("pword");
    var confpword1 = document.getElementById("confpword");

    if (password1 != confpword1){
        window.alert("passwords don't match")
    }else{
        window.alert("well done they do match")
    }

    }
```

surely this code should work? currently whatever i type in, it never hits the else block.
any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Learn to debug with console `console.log(password1, confpword1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your if like this

```
 if (password1.value != confpword1.value){
   window.alert("passwords don't match")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the right syntax

```
if (password1.value != confpword1.value){
        window.alert("passwords don't match")
    }else{
        window.alert("well done they do match")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.value` to get the value of the input field. The correct syntax will be :

```
 if (password1.value != confpword1.value){
        window.alert("passwords don't match")
    }else{
        window.alert("well done they do match")
    }
```